# What does `touch` method do in assets pallet?

Tags: pallet

I am currently looking at the assets pallet and I don't really understand what the touch method does. Hope someone can explain it to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, the `touch` method creates a new "Asset Account" for the "User Account".

I suspect that the `touch` name comes from the unix command called 'touch' which creates a new file if it does not exist already. (sort of, don't worry about it).

In the v4.0.0-dev source for the asset pallet, you can see in the lib.rs that `Touch` calls `do_touch`, which we can find in functions.rs.

If we look at that `do_touch` function, we can see that it checks if the "User Account" already has an entry for the "Asset Account", and if it does not it inserts a new "Asset Account" for the "User Account".

Comment: I am not totally sure if the function name comes from the Unix command touch because it is actually a command that updates the last time modified field of a file, but yeah it can be used to create new files. Anyway, it isn't really important where the name comes from. Thanks for the clarification!